# Difference between "me/messages" and "me/mailfolders('inbox')/messages"

Tags: rest, office365, webhooks, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

I am trying to create a Microsoft Graph Webhook to subscribe the emails.

What is the difference between these two **Resource** in [this Webhook doc](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/subscription_post_subscriptions)? Thanks

`me/messages`

`me/mailfolders('inbox')/messages`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages`

  Represents a top-level "messages" resource that provides access to all messages. You can then filter them using optional parameters.

  [For example](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/use_the_api), adding the following filter parameter restricts the messages returned to only those with the emailAddress property of jon@contoso.com.
  `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?filter=emailAddress eq 'jon@contoso.com'`
- `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailfolders('inbox')/messages`

  Resource represents messages in a specific folder ('inbox' folder in this case).

Comment: looks like paging is not possible for `/me/messages` - can you confirm?

Comment: looks like you can't use this to get all the messages in a users mailbox. It seems to only have the top 100 or so